# How to fix AMPPS showing blank page

Tags: ampps

Randomly stopped being able to load any sites configured within AMPPS.

The pages would just load a blank white page with no content or errors.

I could successfully load the AMPPS config page at `http://localhost/ampps/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stop both Apache and MySQL
2. Navigate to PHP settings tab
3. Click `change PHP version`
4. Change to a different version and click `apply`
5. Change back to the original version and click `apply`
6. Start Apache & MySQL